# How can I remove this thermostatic mixing shower faceplate?

Tags: plumbing, shower, plumbing-fixture

This shower has a temperature selection knob, which operates separately from the water pressure/on-off knob.  The selection is unresponsive, water temperature does not rise or fall when the knob is twisted.

[image: The temperature selection knob]

I thought I'd start by taking the faceplate off and learning more, possibly replacing a cartridge.  But pulling off the faceplate is blocked by the black ridged ring on the knob:
[image]
I see no indication of the manufacturer or model of this shower.  Any advice for how to proceed?  This is what it looks like behind the knob, peeking behind the faceplate when it's slid out as far as I can:
[image]

It seems like I might be able to address the problem there.  But with the faceplate on, I can't access those parts.  Other detail in case relevant: this temperature selector knob controls three shower heads, two of which share one on-off knob and the third on a separate on-off.

Comment: I believe that chrome cap on the front of the knob needs to be removed. The valve I have is similar. Look all around the temp control knob for an inset set screw that takes a small allen wrench to remove. The other possible option is the chrome cap needs to be carefully pried of. In either case I think you'll find the key to removal of the knob is on the knob somewhere not behind the escutcheon.

Comment: @HoneyDo, I believe this is correct and can be provided as an answer!

Comment: Your advice was good and if you post it as an answer I'll accept it.  In the end the chrome cap unscrewed from the end.  It was stuck on there, I used a pipe wrench with a piece of rubber as to not mar the finish.  And I identified the faucet as a Grohe Grohmix 34 419.

Comment: And the chrome cap screws off in the typical counter clockwise direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that chrome cap on the front of the knob needs to be removed. The valve I have is similar. Look all around the temp control knob for an inset set screw that takes a small allen wrench to remove. The other possible option is the chrome cap needs to be carefully pried off. In either case I think you'll find the key to removal of the knob is on the knob somewhere not behind the escutcheon.